# Force Limit jQuery Selectors Only On Portions of the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going out on a limb here but I thought I'd ask...

Let's say I have a ton of plugin initializations on my page
like

```
$('.my-element').somejqueryplugin();
```

and I want to use AJAX to reload part of the DOM on the page.

I need to re-initialize all my plugins for the newly loaded DOM

But...that would cause issues since for DOM that didn't get reloaded I'd be re-initializing the plugins which would cause errors.

I know your standard ways around this (using more specific selectors or destroying the plugins before initialization) - but **I'm looking to see if there's any trick I can use without modifying the selectors (or anything else) on existing JS**.

Can anyone think of any cool hacks for this?

Comment: Yeah, have said plugin add it's own class on initialization (or do it yourself) and then omit said elements by class when applying after ajax (and repeat)

Comment: Adding to what @Charlie said, you could even write a plugin that does that :) so: $('.my-selector').applyPlugins(['pluginOne', ...]) would implement something like the code Charlie wrote above.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without editing almost any of the existing JS - the class idea is solid but I'd still have to edit all the selectors and enforce this as standard later on. Background - I'm trying to create a utility for loading AJAX partials, I want devs to be able to implement it easily on legacy JS without having to modify almost anything. In the past they've had a ton of issues with re-initilizing JS on dynamically loaded components.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by passing a second parameter to the jQuery selector which is the context to which the first selector will be applied.  Given the following HTML snippet

```
<div>
  <p> Regular page stuff</p>
  <div id="ajax-container"></div>
</div>
```

after your ajax call populates the `div#ajax-container` you can execute code on only the ajax added DOM elements with

```
$('.my-element', '#ajax-container').somejqueryplugin();
```